# Integrate Google Crashpad with Linux application

Tags: c++, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I'm trying to integrate Google's Crashpad into my application running on Ubuntu.

As per it's [overview design](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/overview_design.md)

[image: crashpad design]

I create one handler process on ubuntu by following this [link](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/#configuring)

Now for the client process, I should register it with the handler via a socket connection.

```
Linux/Android
On Linux, a registration is a connected socket pair between a client process and the Crashpad handler. This socket pair may be private or shared among many client processes.
```

How do I do that?

There is not much information available on internet related to crashpad. Can someone provide link to any working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a special use case that isn't listed here you shouldn't have to do anything with sockets manually. Just create a new instance of `CrashpadClient` at the entry point of your program and call `StartHandler`.

Here's a snippet from BugSplat's [myUbuntuCrasher](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/myUbuntuCrasher) sample:

```cpp
// Start crash handler
CrashpadClient *client = new CrashpadClient();
bool status = client->StartHandler(handler, reportsDir, metricsDir, url, annotations, arguments, true, false, attachments);
```

Here's the full example from [main.cpp](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/myUbuntuCrasher/blob/master/main.cpp):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "client/crashpad_client.h"
#include "client/crash_report_database.h"
#include "client/settings.h"

#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

#if defined(OS_POSIX)
typedef std::string StringType;
#elif defined(OS_WIN)
typedef std::wstring StringType;
#endif

using namespace base;
using namespace crashpad;
using namespace std;

bool initializeCrashpad(void);
StringType getExecutableDir(void);
void crash(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    initializeCrashpad();
    crash();
}

void crash() {
    *(volatile int *)0 = 0;
}

bool initializeCrashpad() {
    // Get directory where the exe lives so we can pass a full path to handler, reportsDir and metricsDir
    StringType exeDir = getExecutableDir();

    // Ensure that handler is shipped with your application
    FilePath handler(exeDir + "/../crashpad/bin/crashpad_handler");

    // Directory where reports will be saved. Important! Must be writable or crashpad_handler will crash.
    FilePath reportsDir(exeDir);

    // Directory where metrics will be saved. Important! Must be writable or crashpad_handler will crash.
    FilePath metricsDir(exeDir);

    // Configure url with BugSplat’s public fred database. Replace 'fred' with the name of your BugSplat database.
    StringType url = "http://fred.bugsplat.com/post/bp/crash/crashpad.php";

    // Metadata that will be posted to the server with the crash report map
    map<StringType, StringType> annotations;
    annotations["format"] = "minidump";           // Required: Crashpad setting to save crash as a minidump
    annotations["database"] = "fred";             // Required: BugSplat database
    annotations["product"] = "myUbuntuCrasher";   // Required: BugSplat appName
    annotations["version"] = "1.0.0";             // Required: BugSplat appVersion
    annotations["key"] = "Sample key";            // Optional: BugSplat key field
    annotations["user"] = "fred@bugsplat.com";    // Optional: BugSplat user email
    annotations["list_annotations"] = "Sample comment"; // Optional: BugSplat crash description

    // Disable crashpad rate limiting so that all crashes have dmp files
    vector<StringType> arguments; 
    arguments.push_back("--no-rate-limit");

    // File paths of attachments to be uploaded with the minidump file at crash time - default bundle limit is 2MB
    vector<FilePath> attachments;
    FilePath attachment(exeDir + "/attachment.txt");
    attachments.push_back(attachment);

    // Initialize Crashpad database
    unique_ptr<CrashReportDatabase> database = CrashReportDatabase::Initialize(reportsDir);
    if (database == NULL) return false;

    // Enable automated crash uploads
    Settings *settings = database->GetSettings();
    if (settings == NULL) return false;
    settings->SetUploadsEnabled(true);

    // Start crash handler
    CrashpadClient *client = new CrashpadClient();
    bool status = client->StartHandler(handler, reportsDir, metricsDir, url, annotations, arguments, true, false, attachments);
    return status;
}

StringType getExecutableDir() {
    char pBuf[FILENAME_MAX];
    int len = sizeof(pBuf);
    int bytes = MIN(readlink("/proc/self/exe", pBuf, len), len - 1);
    if (bytes >= 0) {
        pBuf[bytes] = '\0';
    }

    char* lastForwardSlash = strrchr(&pBuf[0], '/');
    if (lastForwardSlash == NULL) return NULL;
    *lastForwardSlash = '\0';

    return pBuf;
}
```

More information about configuring Crashpad in Ubuntu can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/linux/).